# Calling perl CGI with jquery $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, server-side

I am trying to call a perl script with a .cgi extension through an ajax call with jQuery, but am not having much luck. On the command line the application runs fine, but when calling it with JS in the browser after a click event nothing seems to be returned.

If someone could point out what's going wrong it would appreciated.

FYI permissions are set to 755. The apache2 handler is set for .cgi  .pl .py .ppl and .perl so I know it's not a handler or permissions issue.

.js file

```
function getData() {

var data = $("#textBox").val(); // this contains a small string

    $.ajax({
        url:"/public_html/cgi-bin/emailSubList.cgi",
        type:"GET",
        data:"data="+data,
        async:false,
        success:function(res){
            alert("result is: " + res);
            }
       }); 
  }
```

.cgi perl script

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl

use CGI;
use DBI;
use strict;

my $in = new CGI;
my $dataIn = $in->param('data');
#this connects, but I don't need to share the login to all
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database:username:password);
my $sth;
my $result;

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM dataList WHERE data=?");
$sth->execute($dataIn);

my @res = $sth->fetchrow_array();

if(@res > 0) {
    $result = 'Data has already been submitted';
}
else {
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO dataList ($dataIn) VALUES (?)");
$sth->execute($dataIn);

$result = 'Data added!';
}

print $in->header('text/plain;charset=UTF-8');
print "$result";
```

UPDATE: there is an error being thrown, 500 internal server error, but I'm not seeing why since the permissions are 755 and the syntax checks out ok with perl -wc script_name.cgi any thoughts on how to debug this or other things to check for would be very helpful.

The above is called with a click event in a web page, but it doesn't seem to execute the perl app. The goal here is to get data sent to a DB and return it, or something else, from the same DB with a simple ajax call.

Comment: Are any errors logged at server? Have you tried attaching `error` property to `$.ajax()` call? Why is there and extra `}` at JavaScript? Is `data` defined at JavaScript? Is code within `$(function(){})`?

Comment: Nope, no errors are logged. That extra } was just a typo. data is declared as a variable, does there need to be another data for the ajax to work properly? And I'm not sure what you mean with that last question.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/ready/. Why use `async:false`?

Comment: Code that is similar to what I am trying do used async:false so I added it in hoping it would work the same. I don't have that code readily available though, so it was an off memory sorta thing. Would recommend against it and why? Also no I haven't coded a .ready() anywhere, so far my JS file is just this function.

Comment: You need to wait for DOM ready or one of the other delay techniques, otherwise when you do `$("#textBox").va()` "textBox" might not even exist yet.

Comment: So a console.log() show that the value is there when the button is clicked on. Any thoughts on how the script isn't executing? The value is there, permissions are there, its executable, and command line works.

Comment: Probably not the problem, but you're missing closing quote on the DB connection string. I suspect this is due to you changing the `username:password`? If not, then that would be a problem.

Comment: Looks like this line `$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO dataList ($dataIn) VALUES (?)");` should probably be: `$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO dataList (data) VALUES (?)");`

Comment: That's just dummy code. I don't need to share to the IT world my database's login credentials ha ha. The actual script runs them just fine and closes the connection. I must have forgotten to paste that in.

Comment: --SOLVED-- So for those who use Blue Host VPS or have an apche server that doesn't read binary CGI files make sure that the file is in or uploaded in ASCII mode. I downloaded the script then uploaded it in FTP with ASCII mode and boom instant success! What a headache over something dumb...live and learn right? Hope someone else can learn from this question

Comment: @CoderLee See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @CoderLee: Please post your solution in an answer (and accept it).

Comment: @CoderLee: Please use `CGI->new` instead of `new CGI`. Your future self who doesn't have to debug one of the obscure corner cases where `new CGI` fails will thank you!

Comment: @CoderLee: CGI programs? In 2017? Why?

Comment: @DaveCross cos it's simple and easier to deploy a script (in any language) that uses CGI (the interface not the module) than most other options?

Comment: @ChrisTurner: Oh I don't care if people want to deploy their code in a CGI environment (well, I think it's a stupid idea, but people do stupid things, right?) But even if you're targetting a CGI environment, writing something using PSGI/Plack is easier and more flexible.

Comment: @DavrCross I'm brushing up on CGI one because it is effective and well maintained from the gnu crowd, in my opinion, and two because my work uses a ton of it so I need to get better at writing it. Since you are adamantly opposed to it what's your preferred web scripting?

Comment: @CoderLee: Well, I prefer to call it "web development", rather than "scripting" as I see "scripting" as a mildly disparaging term. Personally, I write a lot of web apps using Dancer, but anything that is based on PSGI (even raw PSGI, without a framework) will make your life easier. It gives you more power and flexibility and is easier to write. And you get complete flexibility over deployment too. You can deploy as a CGI program or using FCGI or a mod_perl handler. All without changing a line of code.

Comment: @CoderLee: If you're getting a 500 error in the browser, then you'll see more useful information in the web server error log. (And, as an aside, this kind of debugging is one of the things that is easier when you're using PSGI).

Comment: @Dave Cross: Thanks for the info I'll have to work of building some apps with PSGI. And any Idea as to why a newer user can't answer their own question? I tried to do so yesterday and today but SO won't let me

Comment: @CoderLee Probably something to do with [user privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) but I can't see anything obvious.

Comment: @Dave Cross Maybe I just need to acquire more reputation points. Thanks for giving a very good answer though.

Comment: @Dave Cross I tried to up vote it but I'm not at enough rep points to do so yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP has posted a comment explaining that the problem has been solved. As he doesn't seem to want to post an answer explaining it for other people who have similar problems, I'll do it.

If you're uploading files from Windows to a Unix/Linux server, then it's important to do that in ASCII mode. That way, all of the Windows-style line-end characters will automatically be converted to Unix-style line-end characters. If you don't do that, then when your file arrives on the server, it will appear to all be on one line (as the Windows-style line-end characters won't be recognised).

This is particularly important for programs which are executes using the shebang line (and, of course, Perl programs fall into that category). The shebang line is supposed to include the path to the program which is used to execute the code. And if that line doesn't end you are very likely to get some very strange behaviour.

It's worth adding a couple more points:

- This problem will almost certainly have left a useful message in the web server error log.
- This is a good reason why it's well worth developing on the same platform that you will be using for deployment. With good virtual machine environments available for free for all platforms (including Windows), there is no reason why you can't develop in Linux on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just noting some issues I can see in the script as it's posted. Sorry if these are things that were copy paste errors from posting to stackoverflow, rather than the core issues.

1. Database connection string is missing a closing quote.

---

2. The insert statement looks incorrect

---

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO dataList ($dataIn) VALUES (?)");
```

should be:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO dataList (data) VALUES (?)");
```

Comment: Thanks! Well spotted, but you were right about copy and paste. My queries run fine on command line. I just can't find a way to get Apache to run the darn script...

Comment: No worries. Have you tried accessing the script via curl on the local host to see if there is more information on the 500 error? Likewise using Chrome to access the script directly `http://localhost/script.cgi?data=test` and see if the 500 error response body has information you can use to debug?